# Are extensible GADTs a viable solution to the expression problem?

Tags: haskell, ghc, gadt, subtyping

Consider the following wishful program.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ExtensibleGADTs #-}

data Free a where
    Lift :: a -> Free a

data Free (f a) => FreeFunctor f a where
    Map :: (a -> b) -> FreeFunctor f a -> FreeFunctor f b

instance Functor (FreeFunctor f) where
    fmap = Map

data FreeFunctor f a => FreeApplicative f a where
    Apply :: FreeApplicative f (a -> b) -> FreeApplicative f a -> FreeApplicative f b
    Pure  :: a -> FreeApplicative f a

instance Applicative (FreeApplicative f) where
    (<*>) = Apply
    pure  = Pure

data FreeApplicative m a => FreeMonad m a where
    Bind :: FreeMonad m a -> (a -> FreeMonad m b) -> FreeMonad m b

instance Monad (FreeMonad m) where
    (>>=) = Bind
```

This would introduce a notion of [substitutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). For example, a `FreeApplicative f a` can be substituted by a `FreeFunctor f a` but not a `FreeMonad f a`. Similarly, a `FreeApplicative f a -> Int` can be substituted by a `FreeMonad f a -> Int` but not a `FreeFunctor f a -> Int`.

The notion of [subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) can be captured using injections.

```hs
import Unsafe.Coerce

fromFreeToFreeFunctor :: Free (f a) -> FreeFunctor f a
fromFreeToFreeFunctor = unsafeCoerce

fromFreeFunctorToFreeApplicative :: FreeFunctor f a -> FreeApplicative f a
fromFreeFunctorToFreeApplicative = unsafeCoerce

fromFreeApplicativeToFreeMonad :: FreeApplicative m a -> FreeMonad m a
fromFreeApplicativeToFreeMonad = unsafeCoerce
```

The compiler would insert these injections as and where required.

I think that this is a good solution to the [expression problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem). However, the [general consensus](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/423o0c/why_no_subtypingsubtype_polymorphism/) is that subtype polymorphism would be problematic in Haskell. So, my question is two fold.

1. Would subtyping, as I described above, be problematic or interfere with type inference in Haskell?
2. Would extensible GADTs be a viable solution to the expression problem in Haskell?

I haven't defined a precise semantics for extensible GADTs yet. If this seems like something worth pursuing then I'd like to write a GHC extension for this. Just wanted to put this idea out in the wild and get some criticism.

Comment: I don't think you need GADTs. Tom Schrijvers once gave a talk at the *Leuven Haskell User Group* about this: https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~tom.schrijvers/Research/talks/lhug2.pdf